# how do i change column ratios with jeet?

Tags: css, stylus, jeet-grid

I am trying to change my column ratio from 1/4 to 1/3.

The default style is 1/4,

```
col(1/4, gutter: .5, cycle: 4)
```

Then I uncycle and switch to 1/3,

```
+below(desktop)
  uncycle()
  col(1/3, gutter: .5, cycle: 3)
```

the cycle remains at 4 leaving an row with only one column floating to the right.

Comment: if you're simply changing the number of cycled elements I don't think `uncycle()` is necessary - remove that, see if it works?

Answer (score 2):

uncycle should be passed to the col() call...

i.e.

```
col(1/4, gutter: .5, cycle: 4)
+below(desktop)
    col(1/3, gutter: .5, uncycle: 3, cycle: 4)
```

You can pass multiple uncycles as well if you wanted a 1/2 grid under mobile resolutions for instance.

```
col(1/2, cycle: 2)
+above(mobile)
    col(1/3, uncycle: 2, cycle: 3)
+above(tablet)
    col(1/4, uncycle: 3, cycle: 4)
+above(desktop)
    col(1/5, uncycle: 4, cycle: 5)
```

Comment: Can you really pass multiple uncycles? I need to do that, but in a quick test it only seems to use the final `uncycle` in generating the css.

Comment: Sorry, perhaps should have phrased that better... you can have a different uncycle for each media query if you wanted but the uncycle always clears the last cycle...
 I have updated my answer to reflect